# Use hystrix when called service do not return anything or null

Tags: caching, spring-boot, hystrix

I understand that hystrix provides a fault tolerant approach. When a service is not available, the subsequent calls will be passed to fallback when the service is not available.

I have a similar situation but the it is with the cache.

I have a redis cache and a persistence store. If the data is not present in redis cache, the call should fallback to the persistence store.

Please advise on how can we achieve this.

Is there anything else I can use especially for the case like this i.e. Servcie is available but data is not found from the original service call.

Comment: Ehrm that is the whole point of springs caching abstraction.. It has nothing to do with Hystrix.

Comment: Okay.  Could you please suggest some using which I can achieve the above mentioned?

Comment: Just use Spring Cache as it is told in the reference guide.